# How to protect a range of cells in excel file from another one(which containt vba code)?

Tags: vba, excel

I want to protect a range of cells in excel file from another one, I try by this code but it doesn't work:

```
ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rapport1").Select
Range("O26,A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T").Select
    Range("T1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=3
    Range("O26,A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X").Select
    Range("X1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=2
    Range("O26,A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB").Select
    Range("AB1").Activate
    ActiveWindow.SmallScroll ToRight:=3
    Range("O26,A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD").Select
    Range("AD1").Activate
    Selection.Locked = True
    Selection.FormulaHidden = False
    Sheets("Rapport1").Select
    ActiveSheet.Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
```

Comment: what range are you actually trying to protect?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following will lock cell ranges `"A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD"` and apply Sheet protection to prevent changes to those columns. All other columns (e.g. Columns O, Q, S etc.), will remain unlocked:

```
With ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Rapport1")
    .Cells.Locked = False
    With .Range("A:N,P:P,R:R,T:T,V:V,X:X,Z:Z,AB:AB,AD:AD")
        .Locked = True
        .FormulaHidden = False
    End With
    .Protect DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True
End With
```